# Export a JGraphX graph with custom vertex components to an image

Tags: swing, jgraphx

I have a graph which overrides `createComponents` in `mxGraphComponent` to render every vertex as a `JTable`. While I expected that `mxCellRenderer.create*Document` couldn't handle it, I hoped that saving to an image with

```
BufferedImage image = mxCellRenderer.createBufferedImage(graphComponent.getGraph(), null, 1.0, null, graphComponent.isAntiAlias(), null);
ImageIO.write(image, "PNG", new File("C:\\Temp\\graph.png"));
```

would (of course, now that I look at it, it obviously can't: it only gets `mxGraph` as input, not the `mxGraphComponent`!). Is there a way to save a graph as an image including the custom renderers?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for my use-case

```
JViewport viewport = graphComponent.getViewport();
Color savedBackground = viewport.getBackground();
viewport.setBackground(new Color(0, 0, 0, 0));
try {
    Dimension size = viewport.getPreferredSize();
    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(size.width, size.height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    Graphics2D g = image.createGraphics();
    viewport.printAll(g);
    g.dispose();
    try {
        ImageIO.write(image, "png", target.getFile());
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        NotificationsUtil.showError("Failed to save image", e1);
    }
} finally {
    viewport.setBackground(savedBackground);
}
```